# Adding NumpyArray Values in RDD Python from Dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

How do I add the values from the dictionary in RDD, ***respectively***?

I have the following:

```
my_model = sc.parallelize([("Smith", np.array([1, 0, 3])), ("Johnson",np.array([2, 4, 1])), ("Brown",np.array([1, 1, 2]))])
```

I want the final output to be the following in numpy array:

```
[4, 5, 6]
```

How do I get this added output in numpy array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` function to add the values in the RDD:

```
from operator import add
result = my_model.map(lambda x: x[1]).reduce(add)
```